# soap lite pass string argument

Tags: web-services, perl, soap

I have a problem passing a string argument using Perl. The following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use SOAP::Lite;
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('http://localhost:8080/greeting?wsdl');
print $service->greetClient('perl wooooo'), "\n";
```

Results in

> Greeting **null**! Have a nice day...

A similar python code

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('http://localhost:8080/greeting?wsdl')
print client.service.greetClient('python wooooo')
```

works perfectly

> Greeting **python wooooo**! Have a nice day...

I tried to set different encodings

```
print $service->encoding('utf-8')->greetClient("perl wooooo"), "\n";
```

with the same result.

A SOAP Monitor shows that there is no arg0 in a case of Perl

```
<greetClient xsi:nil="true"  xsi:type="tns:greetClient" />
```

which is present in a case of Python

```
<ns0:greetClient>
  <arg0>python wooooo</arg0>
</ns0:greetClient>
```

What can be a problem?

Why it's so complicated to implement a SOAP client with Perl compared to Python?

EDIT:
**SOLUTION**

Finally the following solution is working

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;

my $soap = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new('c:/temp/greeting.wsdl');
my $call = $soap->compileClient('greetClient');
print $call->(arg0 => 'perl wooooo'){'greetClientResponse'}{'return'}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOAP::Lite` can be infuriatingly bad. You might give `XML::Compile::SOAP` a try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;

my $soap = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new(
    'http://localhost:8080/greeting?wsdl',
    schema_dirs => [
        'c:/soft/Perl/site/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP11/xsd'
        'c:/soft/Perl/site/lib/XML/Compile/XOP/xsd'
        'c:/soft/Perl/site/lib/XML/Compile/xsd'
    ]
);
$soap->compileCalls;
my ( $response, $trace ) = $soap->call( 'greetClient', arg0 => 'perl wooooo' );
$trace->printResponse;
```

`$response` will be the call response converted to a hashref via `XML::Simple`, which may be all you need. The `$trace` object is handy to see what the raw XML response looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not a Perl expert. I found the SOAP::WSDL here http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/ . How can I install it? ppm does not show it in the list?

Comment: I'm working on Windows and perl Build.PL does not work because it looks for gcc and other stuff. Ideally I want to install a package as I did for SOAP:Lite with the ppm.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just taking the opportunity to vent about `SOAP::Lite`. Perhaps `SOAP::WSDL` isn't available for ActivePerl. Do you see `XML::Compile::SOAP`? I'll update my answer to use that if so.

Comment: I got another error. Please take a look on my EDIT in the post

Comment: See edit. You don't need to set that environment variable, and I'm not sure how often a semicolon-separated string is construed as a list in Perl or Python libraries.

Comment: does this support mtom?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't see your WSDL.

But in regards to SOAP::Lite, I don't see you setting up neither a `proxy` (endpoint) nor an `uri`.

You're also probably going to have to change the `on_action` behavior as well. By default, `SOAP::Lite` wants to use the '#' concatenation.

So something along these lines might work.

```
$service->proxy( $uri_of_my_end_point );
$service->uri( $schema_namespace );
$service->on_action( sub {
    my ( $uri, $method ) = @_;
    my $slash = $uri =~ m{/$} ? '' : '/';
    return qq{"$uri$slash$method"};
});
```